# Linearity of expected value of random vectors

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_k$ of $Z$ i.i.d. in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A sample mean

\begin{equation}
\bar{Z}_k = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k Z_j
\end{equation}

by the strong law of large numbers is

\begin{equation}
\bar{Z}_k \to x 
\end{equation}

almost surely as $k \to \infty$.

The variance of $\bar{Z}_k$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{k^2} \mathbb{E} \left( \left\| \sum_{j=1}^k (Z_j -x ) \right\|_2^2 \right)
\end{equation}

in which cases can obtain the equality?

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{k^2} \mathbb{E} \left( \left\| \sum_{j=1}^k (Z_j - x ) \right\|_2^2 \right) =
\frac{1}{k^2} \sum_{j=1}^k \mathbb{E} \left\| Z_j - x \right\|_2^2
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

It is true by independence of $Z_j$'s. Note that $Z_i-x, 1\leq i \leq n$ are orthogonal since they have mean $0$ and they are independent. For orthogonal vectors $(v_i)$ we have $\|\sum v_i\|^{2}=\sum \|v_i\|^{2}$.

Comment: How can we relate orthogonality with zero mean? Do we assume mean 0, since $\bar{Z_k} \to x$   almost surely for large enough $k$ ? Can you please elaborate a little more about it?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random vectors with mean $0$ then $E \langle X, Y \rangle=E\sum X_iY_i=\sum EX_iY_i=\sum EX_i EY_i=0$. @Lin